# how can I use agFiltersToolPanel inside my custom tool panel in ag-grid angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I want to add header and one cancel button in my ag-grid side-bar on the top. Below that I want toolPanel: 'agColumnsToolPanel'.
I think one way to do that is by adding custom tool panel. But I dont know how to add agColumnsToolPanel inside custom tool panel.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW5MK.png)
I want header at the top also I want to add subheading with cancel button. rest all the functionality I want same as default agFiltersToolPanel and agColumnsToolPanel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.